# The Tzidokim and Halacha

Tags: halacha-theory, mishna, sadducees

During Beis Sheini, as far as i understand the tzidokim were the majority of Cohanim at the time. And as far as i understand they sat on the Sanhedrin. When we see a machlokes in the Mishnah and we see the Chochamim rule one way and someone else another way. Did the Tzidokim vote and have a connection with the takkanos of the Chazal?

Comment: Can you please provide a *Jewish* source that Tzidokim were allowed to be members of the Sanhedrin?